# postgres subquery uses ungrouped column

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a query in which I am trying to add a column which contains a percentage of records which have a certain value versus the total number of records. I can get the subquery to work on its own, but when I plug it into the main query it fails with an error :
`ERROR:  subquery uses ungrouped column "ipam_addresses.host_id" from outer query`

my query is:

```
select 
    ipam_networks.ipam_id, 
    ipam_networks.net_name, 
    ipam_networks.net_cidr, 
    zone, 
    count(*), 
    to_char(100*(select count(*) where ipam_addresses.host_id = 0) / (select count(*)), '999D99%') v 
from 
    ipam_addresses 
left outer join 
    ipam_networks 
    on ipam_addresses.parent_id = ipam_networks.ipam_id 
where 
    ipam_addresses.ip_state != 'DHCP_FREE' 
group by  
    ipam_networks.ipam_id, ipam_networks.net_name, ipam_networks.net_cidr;
```

Why is it throwing this error even if I specify the table name in the subquery, and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using a filtered aggregate, no need for subselects at all

```
to_char(100 * (count(*) filter (where ipam_addresses.host_id = 0)) / count(*)::numeric, '999D99%') v
```

The cast `::numeric` is needed to avoid integer division

Comment: I get a syntax error at "filter"

Comment: Then you are using an outdated Postgres version